# how to get textbox value from View to ViewModel in Silverlight MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Currently now i'm using silverlight5 with MVVM. in SL5 i need to do the following.
I have 3 textbox and 1 button control and i datagrid in the xaml(Design page).

here is the Design View(Xaml):

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <VC:EmployeeListViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <my:DataGrid x:Name="McDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="130,151,0,0" Height="137" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowBackground="#AA5D9324" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="193">
        </my:DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Show Message" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="256,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <si:CallDataMethod Method="AddEmployeeCommand"/>
                    <si:ShowMessageBox Caption="Thank you"
                                       Message="Thanks for trying the Example"
                                       MessageBoxButton="OK"/>
                    <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
            PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,12,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="First Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Fname}" />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,44,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Second Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,44,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,75,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Department:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,75,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <!-- Add reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll, System.Windows.Interactivity.dll -->
            <!-- Use mvvmxmlns snippet to add i and ei namespace prefixes -->
       </ComboBox> 
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,122,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Choose:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

in the same project i create one folder named 'ViewModel':
in the same folder i add one class file named: EmployeeListViewModel.cs

my question is this. how to pass the textbox value to the viewmodel[EmployeeListViewModel]  and insert the it to the Datagrid.

EmployeeListViewModel.cs:

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

        public EmployeeListViewModel()
        {
            Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData ();
        }

        private Employee _SelectedEmployee;
        public Employee SelectedEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedEmployee;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedEmployee = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            }
        }

        private Employee _Names;
        public Employee Names
        {
            get
            {
                return _Names;
            }
            set
            {
                _Names = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Names");
            }
        }

        public void HandleShowMessage()
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Hello " + Names + ",Welcome to EventTrigger for MVVM.");

        }
        public RelayCommand _AddEmployeeCommand;
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a command that show the customer.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand AddEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AddEmployeeCommand == null)
                {
                    _AddEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => this.AddEmployee(),
                        param => this.CanAddEmployee
                        );
                }
                return _AddEmployeeCommand;
            }
        }

        public bool CanAddEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                 return true;
            }
        }

        public void AddEmployee()
        {
            //Employee newEmployee = new Employee("New1);
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee() **{};**
           --> **Here i have to pass the value.. How is it possible..?**
            Employees.Add(newEmployee);
            SelectedEmployee = newEmployee;
        }



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        // [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: yup true one.. but i have one doubt already i declare the property in <Employee> Class for get and set values. here my question is why we need to create private string _employeeName; 
    public string EmployeeName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _employeeName; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _employeeName= value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("EmployeeName"); 
        } 
    }     this one to get values. is there any alternate way for getting textbox value from view to viewModel. If yes means please tell. and thank u , u saved my time a lot

Comment: You can bind to properties on an object - but that object needs to be instantiated - so lets say a NewEmployee object that you have somehow instantiated. You can then either bind direct to its properties as you were initially trying - but two way - and rememebering they need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged too, or secondly, in the VoewModel have the getter and setter access the NewEmployee - eg get{ return NewEmployee.FName}.  - but why bother with that object if all you are going to do is create another one and pass its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure how you are going about this?
Usually I would have the grid bound to the selected employee as you have, then have the values of the text boxes bound to the properties on the selectedemployee. As you change row, these would then update to reflect the values of the currently selected row in the grid.
So then you add a new blank employee and it would have blank values until they were entered in the text box. Of course, you'd need to build in some validation to ensure you don't get loads of blabnk rows added.

If I'm correct in my understanding of how you are wanting to do it, then as it stands the values in the text boxes are not related to the selected row, but are used just to add a new employee with those values? to achieve this I would suggest having the Textbox bind to a string value on the Viewmodel. Currently you have them bound to something that doesn't appear to actually exist. Instead, I'd bind them to their own properties on the view model thus:

```
private string _employeeFirstName; 
    public string EmployeeFirstName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _employeeFirstName; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _employeeFirstName= value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("EmployeeFirstName"); 
        } 
    }
```

and then in the xaml bind to that property - with Mode=TwoWay so that the viewmodel also recieves any updates

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeFirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

then when creating your new employee:

```
    public void AddEmployee()    
    {     
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee() {FName = this.EmployeeFirstName};    

        Employees.Add(newEmployee);    
        SelectedEmployee = newEmployee;    
    }
```

Comment: Yup .. It Works.. I just create Textbox bind to a string value on the Viewmodel but i use <Employee> class insted of String..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `TwoWay` binding mode. For example, `Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Fname,Mode=TwoWay}"`. You can read more about [Binding.Mode on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i create three property named Fname,Sname,Dept respectly in View Model..

```
private string _fname;
        public string Fname
        {
            get
            {
                return _fname;
            }
            set
            {
                _fname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Fname");
            }
        }
```

And the function is as follows..

```
public void AddEmployee()    
    {     
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee() {Fname=this.Fname;Sname=this.Sname;Dept=this.Dept};    

        Employees.Add(newEmployee);    
        SelectedEmployee = newEmployee;    
    }
```

It Works Well..

Design Code is :

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,12,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="First Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Fname,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,44,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Second Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,44,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Sname,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,75,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Department:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,75,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Text="{Binding Path=Dept,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<Button Content="Show Message" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="256,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <si:CallDataMethod Method="AddEmployee"/>
                    <si:ShowMessageBox Caption="Thank you"
                                       Message="Thanks for trying the Example"
                                       MessageBoxButton="OK"/>
                    <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
            PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Hope it will useful to us..